# How to copy Postgresql database schema to prisma schema

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am using prisma and PostgreSQL. My PostgreSQL database filled with some data. Is it possible to get Postgresql database schema and set it to prisma schema or something?
 I've tried to `prisma db pull` and it changed my schema.prisma then, when I am trying to create migration it wants to reset my Postgresql database (even if I am doing `--create-only`). 
I've tried to follow https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/database/developing-with-prisma-migrate/add-prisma-migrate-to-a-project. It kinda works:

I pulled schema from PostgreSQL

Created new migration that creates all of my tables

Run this migration and resetted my database `prisma migrate dev`

Applied that initial migration `prisma migrate resolve --applied init`

And tried to deploy this migration to the production

This project must work from another computers. Another users have database with exactly the same schema and it should apply this initial migration without data loss. 
When users pull this project and run `prisma migrate dev` it wants to reset their database too. I've tried to do `prisma migrate resolve --applied init` to user's computer then it cannot run `node index.js` - it cannot find my table's auto-generated types (usersWhereInput, usersCreateInput etc.)

Comment: You mentioned that they cannot find the types, did they execute `npx prisma generate` to generate the PrismaClient?

Comment: @NurulSundarani, Yes they generated prisma client

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run `node index.js`?